# Rebase a git branch and any branches between it and the target branch

Tags: git

Say I have branch `branch-1` based on somewhere back in `master`, and another branch `branch-1a` which is based on the latest commit of `branch-1`. I want to rebase `branch-1` and `branch-1a` simultaneously onto the top of master.

What's the best way of doing that?

Graphically I want to go from:

```
----o---o---o---o - master
     \
      o---o---o---o - branch-1a
           `branch-1
```

to

```
----o---o---o---o - master
                 \
                  o---o---o---o - branch-1a
                       `branch-1
```

I know that I could rebase `branch-1a` and then check out `branch-1` and force reset it on to the correct commit, but that is tedious and I was hoping there might be a one command solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a single command to rebase all of them, but you can use [`--fork-point`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---fork-point) to simplify later rebases:

```
git checkout branch-1
git rebase master
git checkout branch-1a
git rebase --fork-point branch-1
```

Without `--fork-point` (or manually identifying the commit that `branch-1` used to point to) you would see two commits duplicated:

```
----o---o---o---o - master
                 \
                  x---y---x'---y'---o---o - branch-1a
                       `branch-1
```

`--fork-point` tells Git to use the reflog, which should help it recognize that those pairs of commits are "the same" and exclude them from the second rebase.

Answer (score 1):

You will have no other choice to do it one by one:

Rebase `branch1` on top of `master`:

```
git checkout branch1
git rebase master
```

Rebase `branch1-a` on top of **`branch1`**:

```
git checkout branch1-a
git rebase branch1
```

And so on if you have other branches.

Always rebase them on top of their closest base and in this order.